# contenteditable elements with markup for links on the fly (JS, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a lean & clean html/js-based text editor similar to Medium's writing tool. I use contenteditable to make divs editable.

I'd like to add inline markup for text links (e.g. typing `[[Google|https://www.google.com]]` instantly converts into `<a href='https:www.google.com'>Google</a>`, i.e. [Google](https://www.google.com)). All this should happen on the fly, i.e. while typing. That is, when the user types the second closing ] of the link markup or the cursor focus is set outside of a `[[text|url]]` element, JS recognizes this event and instantly converts the `[[text|url]]` into a html link. On the other hand, if the focus is set on an existing text link (i.e., inside an `<a>...</a>` html tag within the editable div, (1) the link's default opening behavior is blocked and (2) the text link is instantly converted back into the markup version for editing (e.g., [Google](https://www.google.com) becomes `[[Google|https://www.google.com]]`).

I am not very familiar with regex in JS. Any idea how this can be done?

Thanks very much for your help.

PS: I use jQuery 1.11.0

PSS: The disired behavior is somewhat similar to this text editor's when backspacing into a link (deleting ] converts the link into the markup version and typing the closing ] converts the markup version into a link). The difference is that I am not separating the writing field from the shown text, everything happens inline.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xu0wjukn/).

It is just a sample.

It converts `[[Google|https://www.google.com]]` to `<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a>`, i.e. [Google](https://www.google.com).

I used [this](http://regexr.com/3bb7g) Regular Expression to detect the inline markup.

It has some bugs, but I think it will help you to implement what you need.

Here is the snippet.

```js
$('.editor').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 221) {
    var text = $('.editor').html();
    var match = /\[\[(.+)\|(https?:\/\/.*\..+)\]\]/g.exec(text);
    if (match !== null) {
      text = text.replace(match[0], "<span><a href='" + match[2] + "'>" + match[1] + "</a></span>");
      $('.editor').html(text);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.editor {
  position: absolute;
  border: black dashed 2px;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor" contenteditable='true'>This is the Editor. write something here.</div>
```